Loopstick vs short whip antennas: performance comparison at 1 MHz (Added: AM frontend amplifier designs for short whip antennas)
How do small loopstick and short whip antennas work on the MW broadcast band? How do they perform and compare each other? Use reasonable and realistic physical parameters for a small pocket radio in suburban areas to calculate the signal level given to the receiver frontend transistor.
Also show what kind of MW AM frontend preamp circuits are effective when used with a short whip antenna.
There have been several small, scattered, generic MW/MF broadcast receiver antenna-related questions where I found incorrect answers posted. Instead of dealing with little comments, I'll do an information dump. The answer below is pretty well established and known in the RF engineering world (there is nothing new, other than I used numbers picked up from the recent questions).

Loopstick
Let's start with a loopstick, using the numbers for a small one used in a "pocket radio" typical of the 1980s. The inductance of a loopstick for a typical 6-transistor superhet was typically 400-500 uH range, but it varied. For straight radios, 300 uH was more typical. We'll use 300uH in this example. The ferrite bar is about 5cm long, with 50mm^2 cross-sectional area, and effective permeability of about 30. Effective permeability depends on the material, length, how the coil is wound on the bar, etc. I used 100 turns, although the actual antennas of this size may be wound about 75 to 95 turns. So, the analysis may overestimate the performance for a 300uH case but may be closer for the 400-500uH case.
The electromotive force (EMF) is the voltage the antenna induces in an unloaded or open circuit. The ratio of the electric field strength and the EMF is called the antenna's effective length. Some literature uses the term antenna factor which refers to the same quantity.
The effective length of a loopstick is calculated by the formula in the first figure, part (1). Incidentally, you can use the same formula for a small loop antenna by using an effective permeability of 1. For this particular loopstick, the effective length is 3.1 mm, which is in the middle of a typical range.
Now, we can calculate the antenna EMF, assuming the field strength of 10 mV/m, a reasonable average strength in suburban areas not too far from the transmission site. For this loopstick, we get 31 micovolts (2).
Next, we can discuss this antenna's equivalent circuit model (3). This loopstick has an internal impedance due to the inductor (300 uH or +j1.9kohm) and the series loss resistance from the inductor. Assuming Q of 100, typical for a small loopstick, we get 19 ohm (XL / Q) series resistance. When the load impedance is very large, we get 31 microvolts.

However, when considering a tuned loopstick antenna, the Thevenin source is inconvenient for analysis, so we should convert it to a Norton source (4). The current source is 31uV divided by the absolute value of the internal impedance 1.9k (ignoring the phase for this purpose). The inductor's loss resistance is now converted to the parallel form, 190kohm (XL * Q). The capacitor will be about 84pF, but we'll continue the discussion using its reactance, -1.9kohm.
Now, with the tuning capacitor added to make the loopstick a resonator, the load voltage can be as high as 3mV when Rload is very high. That factor of 100x came from the Q of the inductor. Note that this voltage boost came with a much higher impedance; it is not an amplification.
Does that number look good?
Wait until you see what a 20cm short whip antenna can do.
Short whip antenna
The length 20cm was taken from a recent question. I did not rig the number to make the number look awesome.
Refer to the second figure for the short monopole antenna.
The effective antenna length of a 20cm whip at 1MHz is about 10 cm. (1) For any short monopole where the length is much shorter than one wavelength is about half of the physical length. (For a 1/4 WL vertical monopole, the effective length is 2/pi times the actual length. The coefficient difference comes from how the antenna current distribution changes with the length.)
The antenna EMF is 1.0 mV in this case. That is 33x higher than the loopstick case (2). However, because the antenna is very short compared to the wavelength, the antenna has a fairly high capacitive reactance, as shown in the antenna equivalent circuit (3). For this case, I just guessed the reactance would be about -50kohm or about 3pF. Not shown in this circuit, but the actual antenna is also subject to ground loss.
Can we tune out this annoying -50k ohm antenna reactance? In theory, yes (4). But don't bother trying in real life. In order to tune this capacitor out, you'll need an inductor of 50k reactance at 1MHz with a reasonably high Q value to be useful. Good luck with that. Suppose you come up with such an inductor and say you have a Q of 100. In order to fully take advantage of such a circuit, you'll need an amplifier with an input impedance of 5Mohm at 1MHz. Good luck with that. But after all, the antenna reactance (-50kohm) fluctuates due to the environment, such as proximity to the body, ground, AC power line, etc., so even if you were able to tune it, it would detune easily and be pretty useless in practice. Theoretical analysis with reality check helps rejecting a bad approach like this.
If one takes the "loading coil" (base loading) approach, the +50k reactance (loading coil) is inserted in series with the antenna. Again, such an antenna would be narrowly tuned, detune with the environmental fluctuation, and impractical. Also, as you'll see soon, such an approach is unnecessary for a receive antenna.

How about combining the short whip with a tuned loopstick, like done in many radio receiver sets? For this calculation, the loopstick receives no signal to make the performance comparison easy.
The Thevenin source model of (3) is converted to a Norton source, then connect a loopstick inductor (with its loss resistance) and a capacitor (tuned at 1MHz... about 81pF). This is shown in (5).
In this circuit, the load voltage can be as high as 3.8mV with very high load impedance. This is an improvement by a factor of 3.8x. This factor could be made larger by using a loopstick with a larger inductance, larger Q or both, but the factor is pretty modest compared to an untuned vs tuned loopstick. But who cares, 3.8 mV is still bigger than 3.0 mV maximum voltage achieved by the tuned loopstick alone. Plus, in real life, both the loopstick and the whip receive the signal power (unless the inductor is shielded like in car stereo tuners).
In either case, the maximum power is delivered to the load when the load resistance is 190kohm. And that power levels from these antennas are very comparable.
So, a small loopstick and a short whip perform practically equally well in receiving MW broadcast signals.
In this Q&A I only discussed the signal level. The signal levels of the 1mV range are considered super strong (59++) by amateur radio receiver standards. The actual receiver performance is determined by the signal-to-noise ratio, rather than the absolute signal level. When trying to receive distant broadcast stations in MW and SW, it is more important to minimize the noise rather than maximize the signal strength. Unlike in VHF/UHF, the receiver noise in MW is negligibly small and amplification is easy with modern transistors. On the other hand, the man-made noise picked up by the antenna is large. Deploying a directional antenna away from the noise source is the key in receiving distant stations clearly.
AM tuner frontend matching/amplifier examples for short whip antennas
We'll use car stereos from the 1970s to 2000s as examples, because car stereos do not use loopstick antennas. (If they did, they would only pick up the noise from the engine/alternator and not the signal, due to the location of the radio.)
The whip antenna is connected through a coaxial cable, which adds about 200-300pF parallel capacitance to the equivalent circuit at MW frequency. That brings the antenna reactance smaller, but also reduces the voltage, due to the voltage division by the capacitors. So, car stereos would require an extra RF amplifier, which we will study in this section.
I chose three radios with the simplest MW frontend; other radios I know had extra bands, which complicated the schematic with the band selector switch and extra components.
Becker Mexico Cassette 375
This was a popular car stereo for Mercedes and Ferrari in the 1970s.

The antenna comes from the top left corner via D1. L1 is a variable inductor with the core moving inside a fixed coil, which is ganged with L2 and L3 (and more from the FM preselector and FM local oscillator). The parallel resonance between L1 and C1, with a linked winding feeding the RF amplifier transistor T201 (BF450) is a very familiar circuit from vacuum radio consoles to tabletop and portable transistor radios. The same circuit was commonly used with loopstick antennas for non-automotive radios. This is probably what most people think of when it comes to an AM radio.
The downside of this type of circuit is the mechanical complexity and the number of steps required to align the radio before shipping out of the factory. However, this radio has more mechanical complexity in the automated station-seeking function and the cassette deck, so it was not a problem.
Becker Mexico Cassette 837/1400/1401
Another classic Becker, this one from the 1980s, the golden era of analog electronics.

The antenna comes from the bottom bundle line labelled "ANTAM" via C251, and amplified by T251 (J105) and T252 (BF370) cascode amplifier. A cascode amplifier of this type has a high input impedance, decent high-frequency gain and gain control through the operating point of T252 (though not used in this particular case).
The input stage of the cascode (T251) is almost always JFET for its advantage in low distortion (less cross-modulation) and dynamic range, although the gain is modest.
This type of cascode amplifier is also common for high-impedance transducers (including microphones, moving magnet cartridges for record players, etc.), and this type of amplifier was popular until highly integrated ICs absorbed the RF amp on the chip in the 2000s. This type of amplifier is one of the essential circuit to study for any radio engineer because it is also used in the IF amplifiers of high-performance receivers of the 1970s through 2000s, often with the AGC control input.
T253 engages F251 inductor when shortwave (KW) is selected.
T254 drives Di250 and Di251 (PIN diodes) for attenuator/AGC.
With much simpler mechanical components, more components are built on streamlined PCB assembly. There is no question that advancement in transistors and diodes naturally lead the evolution, but this shift was accelerated in Japan and West Germany post-1985 due to the new currency exchange rate environment (Plaza Accord) and higher labor costs.
Kenwood KDC-MP5029 KDC-W5031, KDC-W531
A car stereo of the 2000s with an integrated frontend with a discrete amplifier stage. This may be the last generation of radios that had a separate RF amplifier for AM.

The antenna input was duplex filtered (C602, L501, C516, to isolate from the FM preselector circuit) and fed directly to Q501, Toshiba HN3G01J, which comprises a JFET-BJT cascade in a SOT-23-5 package. The output is further filtered/impedance matched through the pi-network and feeds to IC10 to the right, which integrates all the tuners and electronic volume control functions except for the preselector/RF amp and VCO tank circuit.
D501 is Rohm RN739F dual PIN diodes for attenuator/gain control.
Radios of this generation are almost entirely built with surface mount components and an automated PCB manufacturing process.
The later-generation radios are even more integrated with IF-DSP architecture. Pocket radios of the 21st century that use digital tuning and control through integrated radio ICs use the frontend amplifier similar to the car radios of the 1980s forward, rather than the pocket radios of the past, due to smaller inductors replacing larger loopsticks of the past for miniaturization.
Those older Becker and Blaupunkt radios are still highly valued among classic car collectors, and demands for component-level repair and performance enhancements still exist. Not shown here due to complicated schematics, but older car stereos based on germanium transistors of the 1960s are also being restored to match the cars of that era. (Even older car stereos of the 1950s used vacuum tubes.)

Very nice thanks. The voltage and impedance discussion would be complemented with a discussion about the transistor effective noise voltage at this impedance. JFETs vs BJTs? Also perhaps improvements in transistors over the last 40 years that favour whips over loops (though it seems the open whip Z is similar to the resonated loopstick).

I might consider that for a future topic. But the dominant noise source that limits the receiver performance at this point is the noise that comes in from the antenna (rather than a transistor, assuming good engineering). For a high impedance first stage, a typical design is a JFET-BJT cascode amplifier. If used as an external amp, it could be a differential amp or some other circuits, but usually followed by an emitter follower or a transformer to drive a coaxial cable. @tomnexus

@tomnexus I don't know if they still make it, but study Toshiba HN3G01J cascode transistors in one package: http://www.maoye-smd.com/canshu/pdf/2012-8-4/HN3G01J.pdf

@tomnexus I thought about making it a separate Q&A to get a few more points but that is too much work, I just expanded this Q&A and added that stuff at the end.
